# Bootstrap Responsive Image - Keep Right, hide left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Have the following code.

http://www.bootply.com/QAEvSNWph4

What we are needing is when you bring the right side of the screen in, left side of the image collapses (hides).  In the example, basically as we as we reduce the browser width, we need to the Rooster always to be visible.

Any ideas?

HTML Code

```
    <section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
  <div class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(http://beta.madrooster.com/images/carousel_bg.png)">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row-wrapper rodney index">
            <div id="hosting-plans" class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center"> &nbsp; </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 hidden-sm"> &nbsp; </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/.item-->
    </div>
    <!--/.carousel-inner-->
  </div>
  <!--/.carousel-->
  <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev"> <i class="icon-angle-left"></i> </a> <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next"> <i class="icon-angle-right"></i> </a> </section>
```

CSS

```
    @media(min-width:767px) {

#main-slider {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:0px;
}
@media(max-width:767px) {
#main-slider {
  margin-top:50px;
}

}

#main-slider .carousel p {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height:24px;
  color:#FFF;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:400;
  padding-left:0;
}
#main-slider .carousel .btn {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#main-slider .carousel .btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#main-slider .carousel .boxed {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
}
#main-slider .carousel .item {
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
  height: 600px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
}
#main-slider .carousel .item:first-child {
  top: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#main-slider .carousel .item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  z-index: 1;
}
#main-slider .prev,
#main-slider .next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 5;
  outline: 0;
}
#main-slider .prev:hover,
#main-slider .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#main-slider .prev {
  left: 10px;
}
#main-slider .next {
  right: 10px;
}
#main-slider .active .animation.animated-item-1 {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
  -moz-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
  -o-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
  -ms-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
  animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
}
#main-slider .active .animation.animated-item-2 {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
  -moz-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
  -o-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
  -ms-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
  animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
}
#main-slider .active .animation.animated-item-3 {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 900ms both;
  -moz-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 900ms both;
  -o-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 900ms both;
  -ms-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 900ms both;
  animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 900ms both;
}
#main-slider .active .animation.animated-item-4 {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 1200ms both;
  -moz-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 1200ms both;
  -o-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 1200ms both;
  -ms-animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 1200ms both;
  animation: fadeInUp 300ms linear 1200ms both;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    #main-slider .carousel h2 {
      font-size: 42px;
      line-height:36px;
      color:#FFF;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      margin-top:30%;
      font-weight:700;
      padding-left:0;
    }
}

.carousel-indicators li { visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: Links to JSFiddle, Bootply, CodePen, etc need to also include all the relevant code in the question. You were likely warned about this before posting, so please don't ignore those warnings.

Comment: Im not sure I understand this comment.  The example contains all our code and I stated what I was trying to do...

Comment: @Teeoney What he meant is that you need to post the code from your bootply in the question as well, so that when your bootply is deleted or no longer available, this question will still make sense and help others who have the same issue.

Comment: Added the code to the post

Comment: Yeah, Schmalzy has the jist of it. You had a *link* to your code in the question, but you **also** needed to include the *actual* code, so (as he said) if anything happens to the link, your question is still valid.